# virsh cannot set bridge Operation not permitted

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to enable the default libvirt network to be able to create a vm. However when i try to start the default network, this occurs:

`sudo virsh -c qemu:///system net-start default
error: Failed to start network default
error: Unable to set bridge virbr0 forward_delay: Operation not permitted`

with `net-list --all` you can see that it is not running:
`sudo virsh -c qemu:///system net-list --all`

`Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent`

`----------------------------------------------------------`

`default              inactive   yes           yes`

is there another way to start the network. I am not needing to see other devices on the network, just need internet access.

is the problem because it doesn't exist? If I do `ip addr show` it doesn't come up

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 206.---.166.---/32 brd 206.---.---.96 scope global venet0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::2/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: Hi, am I assuming correctly that you are running inside a container, because there I have seen this in [bug 1802906](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1802906) and [bug 1784501](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784501) before. You either need to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 or later to get the fixes or make your containers slightly more privileged as outlines [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1802906/comments/2)

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt This is a VM running in OpenVZ. I guess I will have to wait until they release a later iso. Thanks for your reply